# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'src' of null - simple tictactoe

Tags: javascript, for-loop, mouselistener

Hi trying to learn Javascript on simple tictactoe.  TicTacToe is working.  Trying to add a preview image functionality using mouseenter.  When I do one square works fine.  when i try to loop through all of the squares I am getting Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'src' of null.  Seems like something simple is wrong, but I cant spot it.  Also not sure if there is a better way than using a for loop.  Seems like I should just be able to create a listener that doesnt have to loop through all of the ids each time.  Posting just Javascript for mouseon. Thanks in advance for any help.

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Replace this with your own information -->
    <meta name="author" content="" />
    <title>TicTacToe Potential Solution</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="tictactoe_style.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="mouseOn.js" defer></script>

    <!--  onclick="playerGame()"  onmouseenter="setNewImage()" onmouseleave="setOldImage()"  -->

  </head>

  <body>
  <h1> TicTacToe </h1>

    <table>

      <tr>

        <td>

          <img id="1" onmouseenter="setNewImage()" src="blank.jpg" alt="starting image of Chichen Itza"/>

        </td>

        <td>

          <img id="2" onmouseenter="setNewImage()" src="blank.jpg" alt="starting image of Chichen Itza"/>

        </td>

        <td>

          <img id="3" onmouseenter="setNewImage()" src="blank.jpg" alt="starting image of Chichen Itza"/>

        </td>

      </tr>

      <tr>

        <td>

          <img id="4" onmouseenter="setNewImage()" src="blank.jpg" alt="starting image of Chichen Itza"/>

        </td>

        <td>

          <img id="5" onmouseenter="setNewImage()" src="blank.jpg" alt="starting image of Chichen Itza"/>
          
        </td>

        <td>

          <img id="6" onmouseenter="setNewImage()" src="blank.jpg" alt="starting image of Chichen Itza"/>

        </td>

      </tr>

      <tr>

        <td>

          <img id="7" onmouseenter="setNewImage()" src="blank.jpg" alt="starting image of Chichen Itza"/>

        </td>

        <td>

          <img id="8" onmouseenter="setNewImage()" src="blank.jpg" alt="starting image of Chichen Itza"/>

        </td>

        <td>

          <img id="9" onmouseenter="setNewImage()" src="blank.jpg" alt="starting image of Chichen Itza"/>

        </td>

      </tr>

    </table>

    <h2></h2>
        
    <div class="scoreboard">
        <h3  id="demo"></h3>
        <p></p>

        <button id="reset">Reset</button>
    </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

JavaScript
// jshint esversion: 6

```
//Sets the number of boxes to a constant
//creats an Global immutable constant variable.  
const boxes = document.querySelectorAll("img");


//stores player turn Global variable currentPlayer
let currentPlayer = "cross.png";

function setNewImage() {
    
for (const box of boxes) {  
    //adding mouse on event listener
    box.addEventListener("mouseenter", () => {
        if (currentPlayer == "cross.png") {
            document.getElementById(box).src="cross1.png";
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById(box).src="zero1.png";
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: in your  cycle  box is  not string.  is node . you can use  box.src = 'cross.png' or  you   have to use  sting (id)  for  get node instead of box in  document.getElementById(box)

Comment: What is inside `boxes` ?  Can you please post the content of it.

Comment: boxes is just the NodeList of images as defined by the statement const boxes = document.querySelectorAll("img"); at the top of the program

Comment: console.log(boxes) = NodeList(9) [img#1, img#2, img#3, img#4, img#5, img#6, img#7, img#8, img#9]

Answer (score 0):

You have just to run your `setNewImage` function when the dom is loaded with `onload` attribute and it will be just fine, also you are setting the `mouseenter` event two times one time directly in HTML and another time in `setNewImage` function.

Here is the code :

```js
//Sets the number of boxes to a constant
//creats an Global immutable constant variable.  
const boxes = document.querySelectorAll("img");


//stores player turn Global variable currentPlayer
let currentPlayer = "cross.png";

function setNewImage() {

  for (const box of boxes) {
    //adding mouse on event listener
    box.addEventListener("mouseenter", () => {
      if (currentPlayer === "cross.png") {
        box.src = "https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-44FEkFGb5h8/Ux3Ul5ly3LI/AAAAAAAAEGU/jl4_ktKNJp0/s1600/playX.png";
      } else {
        box.src = "https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-lyELSi3oPWc/Ux3UlhpiAWI/AAAAAAAAEGI/VLvmMCW7aco/s1600/playO.png";
      }
    });
  }
}

function reset(){
  for (const box of boxes) {
    box.src = "";
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Replace this with your own information -->
    <meta name="author" content="" />
    <title>TicTacToe Potential Solution</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="tictactoe_style.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="mouseOn.js" defer></script>

    <!--  onclick="playerGame()"  onmouseenter="setNewImage()" onmouseleave="setOldImage()"  -->

  </head>

  <body onload="setNewImage()">
    <h1> TicTacToe </h1>

    <table>

      <tr>

        <td>

          <img id="1" width="100" height="100" />

        </td>

        <td>

          <img id="2" width="100" height="100" />

        </td>

        <td>

          <img id="3" width="100" height="100" />

        </td>

      </tr>

      <tr>

        <td>

          <img id="4" width="100" height="100" />

        </td>

        <td>

          <img id="5" width="100" height="100" />

        </td>

        <td>

          <img id="6" width="100" height="100" />

        </td>

      </tr>

      <tr>

        <td>

          <img id="7" width="100" height="100" />

        </td>

        <td>

          <img id="8" width="100" height="100" />

        </td>

        <td>

          <img id="9" width="100" height="100" />

        </td>

      </tr>

    </table>

    <h2></h2>

    <div class="scoreboard">
      <h3 id="demo"></h3>
      <p></p>

      <button id="reset" onclick="reset()">Reset</button>
    </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: thanks.  I didnt talk about the next part.  So when I leave the image, it should go back to blank.   Am just trying to preview a move.  But i figured once I got the onmouseenter code working the onmouseleave would be easy.  But you are correct, I initially have to enter the square twice before it starts working properly

Comment: yeah and also you had problems in your event setup

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Сергей Петрашко - this worked

```
// jshint esversion: 6


//Sets the number of boxes to a constant
//creats an Global immutable constant variable.  
const boxes = document.querySelectorAll("img");


//stores player turn Global variable currentPlayer
let currentPlayer = "cross.png";


function setNewImage() {
    
    for (const box of boxes) {  
        //adding mouse on event listener
        box.addEventListener("mouseenter", () => {
            if (currentPlayer=="cross.png") {
                box.src="cross1.png";
            }
            else {
                box.src="zero1.png";
                }
            });
        }
}

function setOldImage() {
for (const box of boxes) {
        //adding mouse leave event listener
        box.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
            box.src="blank.jpg";
        });
    }
}
```